# Visit to Singapore on multiple tourist visa

Tags: indian-citizens

I am an indian-citizen have got multiple visa for singapore valid upto April,2017. My daughter & son in law are staying there for last 4 yrs. I want to visit Singapore in Sept'16 at my daughter's placeand stay there for 30 days. Then from there I will visit to Thailand, stay there for 3-4 days only and want to come back from Thailand to my daughter's place again in Singapore. I will stay with my daughter for 30 days again and thereafter come back to my home land.

Please tell me whether it will be possible or not. Minm. how many days one has to move out from Singapore after 30 days and then again can re-enter for another 30 days stay.

Comment: Related: [How can one stay more than 30 days in Singapore on a tourist visa?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/68144/3221)